# Variance of number of tails in a coin-toss experiment

Tags: probability, expectation

**Let X be the random variable that equals the number of tails minus the number of heads when n fair coins are flipped. What is the variance of X?**

I've run a simulation and the answer seems to be n, but I can't get at it myself. 
$V(X) = E(X^2) - E(X)^2$ and E(X) is zero, so $V(X) = E(X^2)$. Now $X = (2X_t - n)$ where $X_t$ is number of tails. $X^2 = 4X_t^2 + n^2 - 2X_tn$. Taking E() on both sides:

$E(X^2) = 4E(X_t^2) + n^2 - 2nE(X_t)$

we know that $E(X_t)=n/2$
so,

$E(X^2) = 4E(X_t^2) - n^2$

I tried to get $E(X_t^2)$ from a simulation and got the right answer again.

So the question boils down to: How to find the expectation of $E(X_t^2)$ where $X_t$ is the number of tails in n coin tosses.

Comment: If $X_t\sim Bin(n,p)$ then $E(X_t^2)=Var(X_t)+(E(X_t))^2=np(1-p)+(np)^2$. In your case $p=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Got something from an answer below?

Answer (score 5):

Let $T$ denote the number of tails and $H$ the number of heads by $n$ tosses.

$X=T-H=T-\left(n-T\right)=2T-n$ and $\text{Var}\left(2T-n\right)=4\text{Var}\left(T\right)=4np\left(1-p\right)$
where $p$ denotes the probability of a tail by a toss. Note here that the distribution of $T$ is binomial. If the coin
is unbiased then $p=\frac{1}{2}$ leading to $\text{Var}\left(X\right)=n$.

Used is here that $\text{Var}\left(aY+b\right)=a^{2}\text{Var}Y$ for random variable
with $\mathbb{E}Y^{2}<\infty$.

Comment: How does Var(T)=np(1-p)?

Comment: @shachna That is characteristic for [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Variance). I expected the OP to be familiar with that.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $X=\sum\limits_{k=1}^nU_k$ where $U_k=1$ if the $k$th experiment produces tails and $U_k=-1$ otherwise. Then the sequence $(U_k)$ is independent with $E(U_k)=0$ and $E(U_k^2)=1$ for every $k$ hence $E(X)=0$ and $E(X^2)=nE(U_1^2)=n$, in particular the variance of $X$ is $n$.

Comment: Thanks. You say $E(X^2) = nE(U_1^2)$. But $X^2$ is not a sum of $U^2$s is it? Are you not using the linear property of E()?

Comment: Of course--and the fact that the variance of a sum of independent random variables is the sum of they variances.

Comment: Oh yeah, right. Thanks.